# What is the equation that tells us that the universe is expanding?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Well I know that the universe is expanding, but is there any equation or letter or simply just an expression that tells us that the universe is expanding...

Comment: Equations don't tell us things about the universe because the universe isn't required to follow any of our contrived models of it. The best you could get is an equation *such that* if it is accurate it then follows that we can infer that the universe is likely expanding, for instance [Hubble's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law).

Comment: See [Freedmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation). For short, a dark energy-dominated universe is an expanding (acceleration of the expansion to be more precise) one. And our observations are telling us that our universe is an expanding one whose expansion is accelerating.

Answer (score 1):

There are equations that represent the relationships among variables characterizing a **model** of our universe which in many ways match characteristics of our actual universe, but also fail to match many details. The equations can also model similar universes with different characteristics. The equations have parameters which influence the dynamics of the model.

There are several variations of equations called Friedmann equations. One of these in particular is used a lot.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation)

$$\frac {H^2} {H_0^2} = \Omega_{0,R}/a^4+\Omega_{0,M}/a^3+\Omega_{0,k}/a^2+\Omega_{0,\Lambda} $$

There are five parameters:

$$H_0, \Omega_{0,R}, \Omega_{0,M}, \Omega_{0,k}, \Omega_{0,\Lambda}.$$

H and a are functions of time (t) calculated from the five parameters.

$$H(t) = \frac {da(t)/dt} {a(t)}$$

Cosmologists analyze measurements of astronomical data and calculate values for the five parameters that "best fit" the data producing the best model available from the data. Two examples of this data are (1) red-shifts of light of specific known frequencies, and (2) the brightness of objects (e.g. supernovas).

Since the model shows that H(t) is a function that increases its value as time increases, this is one piece of evidence for the expanding universe. It also shows that the rate of expansion is increasing, except that H(t) asymptotically approaches a constant as t gets bigger.

If you have questions about the notation, please ask for an explanation.

Comment: @S.MUKHERJEE Thank you for the edit.  I do not know how to give an URL a different appearance in a question or answer or comment. Can you please educate me about how to do this?

Comment: Thanks Buzz, as you know that i am a 12 year old, I would like you to tell me the meanings of the symbols used in the equations....

Comment: @Tanush H(t) is the Hubble parameter. It may be difficult, but see what you can learn from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble's_law#Determining_the_Hubble_constant. The super script "2" in $H(t)^2$ means $H(t)$ squared, which is $H$ times $H$. $H_0$ is the value of $H(t)$ for $t=now$. The four terms with $\Omega$ are four different kind of mass density divided by what is called the critical density (represented by $\rho_c$). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Density_parameter.

Comment: The subscripts of the four $\Omega$s (R. M, k.$\Lambda$) are for radiation, matter, spacial curvature, and what is called a cosmological constant ( also called dark energy). The numerator of the  bottom equation ($da/dt$) is a derivative, meaning the rate of change of $a$ with respect to a change in $t$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative.  I hope his is helpful. If you would like any specific clarification, please let me know.